# Visual Studio 2012 Shortcut keys From aspx to Code Behind and Code Behind to aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to know the shortcut keys to access from Code-Behind to aspx and aspx to Code-Behind pages.

Comment: it's not F7 and Sitft + F7?

Comment: F7 works fine but Shift + f7 access to aspx page bur in design mode I want to be in Source mode. Do you know how to do it ?

Comment: go to tools -> options. Select Html Designer, then General and, in Start Pages in, select Source Code View or Two Panels View... my visual studio is in spanish so i don't know if options would match.

Comment: F7 and Shift+F7 also to toggle between design-split-source use CTRL+PgUP / PgDN

Answer (score 3):

A rather clear reply

1. From .ASPX page to code behind press <kbd>F7</kbd>
2. From CodeBehind to ASPX Page press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>

When .aspx page is shown, Designer view is shown by default. To see the source code, click "source" tab at bottom. Or use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>PageUp/PageDown</kbd> keys to cycle through source, split and designer view.

Answer (score 0):

From code behind, Create a Macro (Ctrl Shift R)

Press Shift F7
Press Ctrl PgUp

Finish Your Macro (Ctrl Shift R)

Test your Macro (Ctrl Shift P)

Assign a shortcut.