# How to switch from code-behind to ASPX file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, code-behind

With `F7` I can go from the `ASPX` file to its code-behind file (cs) .

How can I do the reversed switch : from the code-behind file to the `ASPX` file ?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094504/visual-studio-2012-shortcut-keys-from-aspx-to-code-behind-and-code-behind-to-asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>F7</kbd> should toggle between the code behind and the source file.  Press <kbd>F7</kbd> again to go back to the source file.

See this post: [Visual Studio hotkey to switch between code behind and source file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320119/visual-studio-hotkey-to-switch-between-code-behind-and-source-file)

Comment: Just pay attention that it throws you back to the ASPX under the Design tag , and you need to switch to the Source tag (under VS2012 ) .